# How Long to Bake Frozen Artichoke Hearts?

Tags: oven, cooking-time, artichokes

I'm a novice cook, but was intrigued by Megan McArdle's simple-enough-even-for-me [recipe for frozen artichoke hearts](http://www.theatlantic.com/personal/archive/2010/09/in-praise-of-frozen-vegetables/63735/):

> I'm also an enormous fan of frozen artichoke hearts, which when roasted at 500 degrees with a little spritz of olive oil and a sprinkling of sea salt, make a delicious, inexpensive, low calorie and high fiber dinner or side dish.  We always have them in our freezer, and after eating same at our house, some friends have started stocking up as well.  Are they quite as good as fresh grown, local artichokes would be?  No.  But local artichokes aren't available for very long in Washington, DC, and I tend to get discouraged by the task of cutting down twelve artichokes to extract the heart.

OK, I have all the ingredients, but a question remains: how long should I bake the hearts at 500°?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the artichoke's size.  The Birds Eye brand common in the US will take  about half an hour at 475°F (I have never timed them, so it's a guess).  I just watch them until they start getting brown spots.  If they are big, lower the temperature.